# user secrets file gets ignored in asp.net core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have two projects targeted .net 6 and there are no any explicit declarations for using user secrets (I remember, it was required in previous versions to use `AddUserSecrets()`). Though, one project gets the right config from `secrets.json`, but another one - tries to get it from `appsettings.json`.

So, I'm wondering, what's the issue? How the behavior was changed in .net 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In .Net6, `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` initializes a new instance of the WebApplicationBuilder class with preconfigured defaults. The initialized WebApplicationBuilder (builder) provides default configuration and calls AddUserSecrets when the EnvironmentName is Development.

As long as you initialize your web application using the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` method, ASP.NET Core automatically picks up your configuration from the secrets.json file in .Net6. If you initialize your application manually or not .Net6,  make sure to call the AddUserSecrets-method.

refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows)

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost is an internal class. Please clarify or provide sample code.